# Mount from auto to manual and changing dir gives errors

Tags: ubuntu, ext4, automounting

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and am trying to mount my internal HD to a different location in the `/home/username` dir (auto-mount mounts it to `/mnt/{uuid}` )

But I ran into a problem.  In Disks, when I switch from auto-mount to manual, all I change is the directory and try to mount, I get an error:

> Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb1: command-line 'mount "/mnt/{uuid}" exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error"

I tried changing from auto to manual and not changing any options, everything was the same – and I get the error again.  But when it goes to auto-mount, it mounts just fine.

I already did a `sudo apt-get install linux-generic`.

What I'm doing wrong and how can I solve this?